# How do you create flexible space header with textview/edittext instead of image?

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design

I would like to create app which has UI similar to the picture below.

> **I have already looked into following library [ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar), [ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView), [kmshack/Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager](https://github.com/kmshack/Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager), [flavienlaurent/NotBoringActionBar](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/NotBoringActionBar) and none of them has this ability to add combination of `EditText`, `Textview` and `ImageView`.**

There is already an application on playstore which has [similar functionality](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.drobek.krzysztof.wemple).

Also what is the official name of **purple** color part?

I am completely frustrated as I am not able to find any `tutorials` or `libraries` to help me with my project.

Any help is appreciated!

[image: Here is the image]

Comment: The purple part is a toolbar, `android.support.v7.widget.toolbar`

Answer (score 1):

You can add views directly to a toolbar as it's a viewgroup. Then you simply set it as your supportActionBar

Code
styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Layout of Main:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

custom toolbar layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark">

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:hint="Enter Text"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:text="Hello world"/>
   </LinearLayout>

   </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.ppoborca.testers;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mTextView = (TextView) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        mTextView.setText("This worked!");
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    }

}
```

[image: my result]

Comment: thank you for your code but i found another one which is much better and also has parallax effect.

Comment: @SamvidKulkarni Can you send me what you better than this  one I need a similar layout to implement in my code...

Comment: @ShamimAhmad Sorry I dont have code anymore, Use this library, it is very easy to understand and works very well. https://github.com/lynfogeek/CollapsingHeader

Answer (score 0):

After searching on internet for 4 days I finally found [this](https://github.com/lynfogeek/CollapsingHeader) example on github which is very easy to use and there is this [blogspot](http://arnaud-camus.fr/material-design-extended-toolbar-and-scrolling/) which explains all the code line-by-line.